# Android RelativeLayout stretch background

Tags: java, android, background, android-relativelayout

all.
this is my layout code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@mipmap/backgroung"
    tools:context=".MainScreen">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30pt"
        android:text="@string/level1"
        android:onClick="@string/level1"
        android:id="@+id/level1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60pt"
        android:text="@string/level2"
        android:id="@+id/level2"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="90pt"
        android:text="@string/level3"
        android:id="@+id/level3"/>
```

It look like is:

[image]

I want that the punch photo will stretch all over the white background.

Thanks for helpers!

Comment: Does the photo have that white area in it? If it does, then it is already stretched out. You can use `android:src` combined with `android:scaletype` instead of `android:background`.

Comment: @Ishita Sinha could you give me an example?

Comment: Background images are going to be stretched independently of the layout type. And... why on earth do you use the `mipmap` folder?!?!?! You should store ONLY THE LAUNCHER ICON in there!

Comment: @Rotwang i right click on the app folder -> new image asset, and it add the new image to the mipmap folder, y is it?

Comment: You must create your drawable folders. AS is stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it,
when add new image asset it resize the image and crop to with white borders.
Need to hard copy-paste the entire photo to the drawable folder.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use a 9patch image here. In which the punch area can be constant and the image can stretch with the blue region. That way you won't face the issue of the image being blurred because of stretching. You can find some good examples of how to create a 9patch from youtube. here's a [sample](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMkuqZC3CxE).

Answer (score 0):

In your RelativeLayout, do you see those `android:paddingTop` and bottom/left/right? Remove all those or change to `="0dp"`.

Move your image into `<ImageView/>` before the buttons.

And use `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Oh, make sure your pic does not have any whitespace border.

Comment: its changes only the button padding, not the background

Comment: Remove padding, move pic to imageview, use scaletype